# Get JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making my first project in React so please be gentle.

I'm having trouble putting react data into a component.

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzLDsxPGctY) I setup the component. The [source code](https://fullstackdiscussion.com/topic/38/source-code-for-react-js-tutorial-how-to-get-data-from-an-api-with-react) from video.

```js
class WeatherInfo extends React.Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                items: [],
                isLoaded: false
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Austin,USA&appid=583f803dfc6a7f2f96ff9957c330c2b0&units=imperial`)
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(json => {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                            items: json                           
                        })
                    });
                }

            render() {

                let {
                    isLoaded,
                    items
                } = this.state;
                if (!isLoaded) {
                    return <div> Loading... </div>
                } else {
                    return ( <div>
                        <ul>
                            {items.map(item => (
                                <li key="{item.list}">
                                    test: {item.list.main}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul> 
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Feeling lost when connecting the JSON into the ul...or whatever I'd like. My recent error is items.map is not a function. But I have a strong feeling even fixing that error won't get the data from the api that I'd like.

[Here's a link](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Austin,USA&appid=583f803dfc6a7f2f96ff9957c330c2b0&units=imperial) to the JSON link where the data is I'd like to use. End project would be selecting only some of the data but I'm confident one I know how to access the data correctly I can do that on my own.

Thank you.

Comment: Because your api is returning the object  and in there is a property named `list` on which you can loop through. [Here](https://jsonformatter.org/f5e90d) is your data format in json

Comment: Your code is fine. the problem is your understanding of the data model. Take a close look at the returned object to make sure you understand what it is you are trying to get into the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code working here is a jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/8q3wbmft/

```
class WeatherInfo extends React.Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                items: [],
                isLoaded: false
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Austin,USA&appid=583f803dfc6a7f2f96ff9957c330c2b0&units=imperial`)
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(json => {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                            items: json                           
                        })
                    });
                }

            render() {

                let {
                    isLoaded,
                    items
                } = this.state;
                if (!isLoaded) {
                    return (<div> Loading... </div>)
                } else {
                    return ( <div>
                        <ul>
                            {items.list.map((item, key) => (
                                <li key="{key}">
                                    test: {item.main.temp}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul> 
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
        } 

ReactDOM.render(
  <WeatherInfo name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Basically what is happening is this:

1. The api is an object:
2. And this object has an array of list
3. This list is an array of objects
4. The key main has the main data temp which you need

If you have questions feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. What if I only wanted certain data and say not all of .temps but, for example, the 2nd temp array?

Like list[2].main.temp

Comment: Yes you got it right just add brackets and add this code like this 

<p>Get 2nd Element {items.list[2].main.temp}</p>… 

Here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/u8r62gcz/1/

Answer (score 2):

URL used in tutorial is returning array of records

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

```
[
{
  "id": 1, .....
}
]
```

While you api end point does not return array of records, it is returning object that's why its failing.

Try this:

```
                       {items.list.map(item => (
                            <li key="{item}">
                                test: {item.main}
                            </li>
                        ))}
```

Comment: Thanks Anil. 

Error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Trying to find the answer myself but some guidance would be helpful too.

Comment: console.log(items) and see what's the structure of response at this point to adjust code. You need to map over an array which is list in response.